# button disabled background color inline style attribute jsx

Tags: css, jsx

I have a case where I can only pass the property to the jsx component but I cannot use standard css class (component is not reachable, only can be styled by passing the attributes to its parent component). Is there a way to set the background-color for a disabled button using inline style attribute?

EDIT
the closest I get is `style: {[disabled=true]:{backgroundColor: "red"}}` but I get Uncaught ReferenceError: disabled is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Something like this should work:

define your style:

```
const disabled = {
  backgroundColor: "red"
};
```

Then wherever your button component occurs:

```
<Button style={disabled}>
  Example Button
</Button>
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask if you are passing disabled into the component as a prop?

If so you can do below

```
const isDisabled = {
   backgrondColor: 'red'
};

<button style={disabled ? isDisabled : null}>
   Button 1
</button>
```